# insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment in linux

Tags: linux, jboss

jboss server in linux environment getting below error.so please suggest how to rectify this error.

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x00000000daaa0000, 44761088, 0) failed; error='Cannot allocate memory' (errno=12)
```

**There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.**

**Native memory allocation (malloc) failed to allocate 44761088 bytes for committing reserved memory.**

Comment: Try increasing your heapsize by setting higher values for -Xms and -Xmx which stands for mininum and maximum heapsize respectively. Something like: `-Xms=512m -Xmx=1024m` for 512MB and 1024MB.

Comment: could you explain how to set or provide -Xms=512m -Xmx=1024m in linux.

Comment: Which JBoss version are you using? Normally you should edit the file `run.sh` in `/jboss/bin/`. Look for the property `JAVA_OPTS` then you should add those values there e.g. like this `set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Xms512m -Xmx1024m ` you have to tune the values until the the ones that work for you.

Answer (score 1):

It will work if you restart due to memory issue.otherwise you have to set your memory like below:

Set the JAVA_OPTS : 
   **JAVA_OPTS=-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m**

Also this is good article about [memory](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-nativememory-linux/).